# UIProgressView progress multiplied by a number returning weird results

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiprogressview

So I have the following code:

```
angle = progbm.progress * 30;  
NSLog(@"%d,%f", angle, progbm.progress);
```

progbm is a UIProgressView (running from 0.0 to 1.0) and angle is a short.

Elsewhere I have code that updates the progress bar either up or down by 0.1. I then seem to get some weird results. Here is the console output:

2011-05-14 15:21:25.265 AppTest[768:307] 3,0.100000
2011-05-14 15:21:26.238 AppTest[768:307] 6,0.200000
2011-05-14 15:21:27.245 AppTest[768:307] 9,0.300000
2011-05-14 15:21:28.061 AppTest[768:307] 12,0.400000
2011-05-14 15:21:28.940 AppTest[768:307] 15,0.500000
2011-05-14 15:21:29.820 AppTest[768:307] 18,0.600000
2011-05-14 15:21:30.716 AppTest[768:307] 21,0.700000
2011-05-14 15:21:31.644 AppTest[768:307] 24,0.800000
2011-05-14 15:21:32.860 AppTest[768:307] 27,0.900000
2011-05-14 15:21:34.460 AppTest[768:307] 30,1.000000
2011-05-14 15:21:39.020 AppTest[768:307] 27,0.900000
2011-05-14 15:21:40.173 AppTest[768:307] 23,0.800000

How does 0.800000 * 30 equal 23?

Comment: You're multiplying a float (`progress`) by an int (`30`), which gives you a float, and then you're using the int format specifier `%d` to print it. Use `%f` instead.

Comment: its alright - I just added a round() in my calculation to ensure that it gives the right result. Just weird behaviour.

Comment: @Richard: I understood sregorcinimod to be saying that the problem was solved and was a simple error. Perhaps I was wrong; in any case, there are now useful answers. I deleted my previous comment suggesting deletion before I saw yours; apologies.

Comment: @Josh I understand. Thanks. @sregorcinimod I'd like to hear if my solution solves this issue for you.

Comment: @richard brightwell - no yours didn't help as the progress bar only progresses on a click so it doesn't run in a different thread. it is simply a rounding anomoly - so the round() solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers to this, either

1) use round() to get the integer value for the short.
2) dont use a short and use a float instead.

I eventually used option 2

Answer (score 0):

My guess is rounding errors that aren't shown with the precision of the NSLog's print.  When you subtract 0.1 from 1.0, you don't necessarily get 0.9.  If I remember correctly, it is impossible to represent exactly 0.1 in floating point notation, because in binary it's a repeating decimal.  So you'll end up with something like 0.899999 or 0.90000001.  Then when you subtract another 0.1 from that, it looks like you're ending up with 0.7999999999 which NSLog is rounding to 0.800000 for printing, but integer multiplication always rounds down, so 23.9999999 is rounded down to 23.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't taking into account that the progress is progressing. :-)  It changes between your calculation and your displaying.  Store progbm.progress into a variable which you use for calc and display and your problem will go away.

Comment: No, the value of progress is not being updated between those two lines, unless this is running on a background thread.